# Convert a string into a character array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Continue on my [Javascript - Radio Button onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819416/javascript-radio-button-onchange)

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function Change(radio)
    {
    for(i = 1; i <=3; i++)
    {
        if(i == radio.value)
        {
            setvalue = "Y";
            value = setvalue;
            radiovalue = radio.value;
        }
        else
       {
            setvalue = "N";
            value = setvalue;
            radiovalue = radio.value;
       }
       ChangeValue(setvalue,value);
    }

    function ChangeValue(setvalue,value)
    {
        var getvalue = value;
        document.write(getvalue);
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
?>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="<?php echo $i;?>" onchange="Change(this)"      /><br />
<?php   
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

From the above code, if I clicked the first radio button, the output is YNN.
Now I want to separate the value with commas (YNN) and put the result into an array ("Y","N","N").

I wrote the following inside ChangeValue function:

```
function ChangeValue(setvalue, value)
{
     var getvalue = value;
     document.write(getvalue);
     var seperate = new array();
     seperate = getvalue.spilt(",");
}
```

However the above code doesn't put my value into array. 
What am I doing wrong? Any solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twhxxyk8/) and see if you can use that as a starting point for your solution. Otherwise please edit your question to make it a little clearer what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `split` the string into separate chars as array.

```
var str = 'YNN'; //or whatever
var strWithComma = str.split(''); //to char array
```

After this you can `join` the chars to a new string for display output.

```
var str = 'YNN';
var strWithComma = str.split('').join(','); //'YNN' (string) --> ['Y','N','N'] (string/char array) --> "Y,N,N" (string)
```

Hope this helps

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ztujorg3/)**

Comment: I will add a demo in a few mins... Im not at home atm

Comment: Ok, I will waiting for you.

Comment: Added a demo. If you have still troubles feel free to let me know

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript String object has a [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method which does what you're requesting. It partitions the string based on a specified delimiter, and returns an array with each partition at its own index. If you split with a blank (empty string) delimiter, you tokenize the string into individual characters.

To get the values of your radio buttons as a string, you can iterate through them and examine the `value` property of each one.

```
var input = "YNN"
var result = input.split(''); // returns ["Y", "N", "N"]
```

```js
var valStr = "";

function main() {
    var radioBtns = document.getElementsByName("choice");

    for (var i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
        radioBtns[i].onchange = valChange;
    }
    valStr = Array(radioBtns.length + 1).join("N")
}

function valChange(event) {
    var changedElem = event.target;
    var elemValue = changedElem.value;
    var elemIdx = +elemValue - 1;
    var resultStr = replaceChar(valStr, elemIdx, 'Y');

    getElem("outputStr").innerHTML = resultStr;
    getElem("outputArr").innerHTML = resultStr.split('');
}

function replaceChar(str, idx, chr) {
    return str.substr(0, idx) + chr + str.substr(idx + chr.length);
}

function getElem(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

window.onload = main;
```

```css
span[id^="output"] {
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 50px;
}
div {
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Select an option:
<br />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="3" />

<div>String Output: <span id="outputStr"> </span>
</div>
<div>Array Output: <span id="outputArr"> </span>
</div>
```